# How do I get this fiddle to work?

Tags: oracle11g, sys-refcursor, sqlfiddle

I have created a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d81b/13) that uses the sys_refcursor. I am unable to get it to work in the SqlFiddle environment.

I am able to get this to work in my local sqlplus environment. Perhaps someone on StackOverflow knows the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen. `VARIABLE pt REFCURSOR` and `print pt` are sql*plus, not sql, commands. Sqlfiddle doesn't know about them.

Comment: If nobody else can figure out this, I will accept your answer.